# Почему disconnect работает неправильно?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Недавно я начал изучать socket.io. С помощью них я хочу отображать всех пользователей, кто сейчас находится онлайн. Вроде бы все получается, но вот только отключение пользователя работает не так, как запланировано. Логика такова: при посещении сайта, пользователь присылает свой логин на сервер, и тот записывает его в массив пользователей, находящихся онлайн. При выходе, логин пользователя удаляется из массива пользователей, находящихся онлайн. Но, при выходе одного пользователя, всех пользователей выписывает из массива. Из-за чего это происходит?

**Server**

```
const users = [];

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('global room', (global) => {

        socket.login = global.login;
        users.push(socket.login);

        socket.join(global.room);

        socket.emit('onlineUsers', users);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        users.splice(socket.login, 1);
        socket.emit('onlineUsers', users);
    })
});
```

**Client**

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('connect', function(){

    var room = 'global room';
    var userLogin = $('#userLogin').val();

    socket.emit('global room', {
        room: room,
        login: userLogin
    });

    socket.on('onlineUsers', function(users){
      console.log(users);
    });
});
```

Comment: Возможно, потому что вы не правильно используете функцию `splice`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я пробовал использовать indexOf логина в splice, но все ровно не помогло

Comment: Ну это надо смотреть каждый конкретный случай. В данном примере кода ошибка как минимум в `splice`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko получилось удалять логин из массива другим способом. Заработало

Answer (score 0):

Изменил

```
users.splice(socket.login, 1);
```

На

```
users = users.filter(login => login !== socket.login);
```

И все заработало корректно